# with lxml, find all td class='banana' but only if they contain the text "Today" in it

Tags: python, lxml

So I would like to get all the a tags inside all the td class="banana" but only if this td contains the text "Today"

```
import lxml.html
html = lxml.html.parse("http://www.sitetoscrape.com/")
a = html.xpath('//td[@class="banana"]//text[@text="Today"]//a')

print a
```

This returns an empty list, if I take out "//text[@text="Today"]" it works, but I get back all the links inside all the td class='banana'

Comment: It would be nice to include a minimal portion of HTML in the question so that people have something to test their solutions on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to give an accurate answer without an example, but something like that should do it.

```
import lxml.html as lh

html="""\
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<td class="banana">
<a>today</a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
</td>
<td class="banana">
<a>bar</a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
</td>
</body>
</html>"""

doc=lh.fromstring(html)

doc.xpath('.//td[contains(.,"today") and @class="banana"]/a')
Out[145]: [<Element a at 1c348b8>, <Element a at 1c34ae8>, <Element a at 1c34c00>]
```